# Conserved charge during renormalization-group flow

Tags: condensed-matter, renormalization

Let us consider a quantum system (at zero temperature) with a continuous (anomaly-free) symmetry $G$ and there exists a corresponding conserved charge $Q$. Then we perturb this (might-be critical) system with some $G$-respecting interactions and do renormalization-group (RG) transformations for this system in a $G$-respecting way. My question is whether $Q$ is an invariant quantity during this RG flow? If not, what extent to which could we say something, if any?

In the previous post, I wrote $Q$ is invariant. But it seems that it depends on the conformal weighting of $Q$, or not?